# Ajax accordion, specific data from a dataset, multiple datasets or distinct data from a dataset possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What i have accordion being loaded with an issue, I want distinct header information and multiple rows in the content.

For example I have a DataTable with the following:

```
Fruit|Apples
Fruit|Mango
Vegetables|peas
```

I want it to result like this

```
Fruit
      -Apples
      -Mango
Vegetables
      -peas
```

This is what I get right now.

```
Fruit
     - Apples
Fruit
     - Mango
Vegetables
     - peas
```

The code i'm using to databind is below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CurrentUserID = HttpContext.Current.Session["userID"].ToString();
    BindAccordion();

}

private void BindAccordion()
{
    viewablePages = new List<string>();
    string storedProcedureName = "GrabAccordionPages";

    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Server="";Database=""; User=root;Password="";"))
    {
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();
        cn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(storedProcedureName, cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usernameID", CurrentUserID);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtTable);
        NavigateAccordion.DataSource = dtTable.DefaultView;
        NavigateAccordion.DataBind();


    }

}
```

My accordion looks like

```
<ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="Server" />
<ajaxToolKit:Accordion ID="NavigateAccordion" runat="server" 
                       SelectedIndex="0" 
                       HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" 
                       ContentCssClass="accordionContent" 
                       FadeTransitions="true" 
                       SuppressHeaderPostbacks = "true"
                       FramesPerSecond="80" 
                       TransitionDuration="200"
                       AutoSize="None"
                       Width="200">

<HeaderTemplate>
  <asp:Label runat="server" Id="lbHeaderId" Text='<%#Eval("service") %'>> </asp:Label>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

Is there a way to manipulate the `<%#Eval("service") %'>>` or do I need to create something besides a DataTable to accomplish what I need.  Or can i bind two datasources to one accordion, but then how do i manage both sources in the content?

Comment: anybody? this cant be that hard...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you were looking for but I would suggest skipping the Microsoft provided toolkits and start using something like jQuery/jQuery UI. I am sure someone in here will be able to help you out.

Comment: I agree.  I used to be big on the .NET AJAX Controls, but I think that the jQuery UI Accordion would be ideal here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089275/databinding-accordion-to-generic-list-in-silverlight  this all most looks like the answer but i've never used ModelData()